# Nachmanides and the Greek proof that the earth is mostly covered with water

Tags: ancient-greece, middle-ages

In the Biblical account of creation, G-d divided the waters. The rabbi and Biblical commentator [Nachmanides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachmanides) wrote about this that he believes the Greek demonstration that the earth is mostly covered with water.

I've been thinking about this statement. At first blush, the portion of the earth covered with water obviously seems to be an empirical question which could not be resolved by any logical argument. But I wonder whether Nachmanides was thinking of an ancient computation about the size of the earth (based on sun angles establishing the degrees of arc between two places at a known distance), coupled with the assumption that someone sailing west from Europe would encounter no land for most of the way to Japan, as apparently anyone would have thought who was unaware of the Americas.

(He would also need some opinion about the size of the known world, but apparently this is the easy part.)

Is there any way of identifying this argument with any greater specificity? What works of Greek geography (or what would the word be?) were available to Nachmanides, and which of these dealt with the question of the amount of the earth's surface covered by water? How widely shared was this opinion?

Comment: Maybe useful Dirk Couprie, [Heaven and Earth in Ancient Greek Cosmology From Thales to Heraclides Ponticus (Springer, 2011)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Heaven_and_Earth_in_Ancient_Greek_Cosmol/MUmdgyUA8bgC)

Comment: According to Aristotle, [Thale of Miletus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales_of_Miletus#Water_as_a_first_principle) advanced the hypothesis that the nature of all matter was a single material substance: water. Thales thought the Earth must be a flat disk which is floating in an expanse of water (an hypotheses that can be quite easy to understand for a society that flourished on the island spread into the Mediterranean Sea).

Comment: What historical documents did Nachmindes provide or reference to back up his position? From the wiki entry it appears he studied only religious texts, which are hardly a reliable source of scientific data.

Comment: The Greeks did not know about existence of Americas, Australia and Antarctica, but nevertheless their conclusion was right: the Earth is indeed mostly covered by water.

Comment: No "proof" at all.. Presumably, a second- or third-hand knowledge of Ancient Greek philosophy and science, through [Maimonides](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/maimonides/).

Comment: @Carl Witthoft At the place where he mentions that the earth's surface is mostly watery, he doesn't mention sources with any specificity. He just says that he believes the Greek argument. That's what prompted my question here. But at that place he uses a Hebrew phrase that might refer to sensory evidence (rather than logical argument). And his commentary is very long.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft At other places, he sometimes mentions the four elements. I'm wondering if he accepted some sort of cosmology in which water surrounds the earth, air surrounds the water and fire surrounds the air. I suppose this would incline someone to the view that the seas' area exceeds that of dry land. Of course I'm not interested in debating Nachmanides' intellectual power with people who have nothing to contribute on that score; I'm hoping to find out here the sorts of Greek arguments probably available to someone in his position in history, that would have led to the mostly-water view.